# How to change the element with no ID in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The HTML codes are like this:

```
<div id="select1_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 250px;">
     <a class="chzn-single chzn-single-with-drop"
      href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
     <span>AFF5</span>
<div></div>
</div>
```

I was wondering how I could change the `<span>AFF5</span>` to `<span>Another</span>` in jquery.
Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: might be interesting to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735359/update-span-tag-value-with-jquery

Comment: There's many ways to skin a cat.  Will it always be in the div with id `select1_chzn`, and will it be the only span in there?  Tell us more and we can answer :)

Comment: Your HTML is malformed, you need to close the A tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could use the id of it parent

```
$("#select1_chzn span").text("Another");
```

**UPDATE**

Using > means direct descendant where as a space means descendant not necessarily direct.

Comment: The `span` isn't a direct child of `#select1_chzn`, it sits within an anchor (which isn't closed in the example markup)

Comment: @billyonecan didnt spot that with not closing tag, will update

Comment: I didn't notice it at first either :p (I didn't downvote btw)

Answer (score 7):

Use the CSS selector

```
#select1_chzn span
```

I am not jquery person, but I have seen enough questions here on SO to guess that you would use

```
$('#select1_chzn span')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#select1_chzn span").text("Another");
```

Simple use of a standard CSS descendant selector should do in this case.

Answer (score 3):

**parent**  **child**, like this:

```
$("#select1_chzn span").text('Another');
```

Answer (score 3):

The title says "How to change the element with no ID in jquery?"

If you want to target all `span`s with *no ID* within the div `#select1_chzn`, you could do

```
$("#select1_chzn span:not([id])").text(...);
```

It seems like you want the *last* `span`:

```
$("#select1_chzn span:last").text(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any available css-selector for selecting jquery objects, for example this should work:

```
$('span').text('Another');
```

Comment: This will set the text of **all** `<span>` elements in the document to 'Another'.

Comment: yes. It was an example for this code, that's why i said 'any available selector'

Comment: Yeah, I just thought I'd mention it, in case OP is not well-versed in css lingo.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually search for spans based on their contents if that is the only way you have of identifying them.

```
​$("span:contains(AFF5)").text( "Another" );
```

However, this is case sensitive.